# Changing user profile may make recent activity log temporarily unreadable

Tags: bug, status-completed, recent-activity, profile-page

I changed the information in my user profile and shortly afterward clicked on (my) user activity log to see whether this action is logged.  Instead of getting the activity log, the page failed to load and reported a system error.  The user profile was edited several times over a span of a few minutes just before testing the activity log, though I did not have to fill out any CAPTCHA as a result.

(edit: activity log on meta can be viewed without problems, the log on the main site is the one that is broken.

edit-2: still broken after 4 hours elapsed. I will test it again in a day or two.)

Comment: @Jeff: Shouldn't the tag be (status-norepro) instead?

Comment: @Rahul: it was reproduced in that other users couldn't load the same activity page, so this was not a local browser problem but something on the SE side.  Editing the user profile has not (so far) reproduced the bug again for me, but I only tried a quick experiment.  Clearly this is not a major problem for me or the site, but it would be interesting to know what could have caused it.  Other than the profile edit all actions during that session were views of public data (questions, user pages, site FAQ, etc) and ordinary comment/answer/edit actions.

Answer (score 1):

Looks OK to me

https://math.stackexchange.com/users/467?tab=activity

Comment: Was OK for me as of about 7 hours after the problem but non-OK until 4-5 hours past.  The error screen that came up said something like "Oops / our fault / problem logged / SE is notified / consider a post on meta", i.e., some problem was triggered, noticed and logged on the SE server side, but I don't know if the connection to profile edit is coincidental.  I could not replicate it with another profile edit after the 7-hour mark.

Comment: T.. is right. I also remember his/her activity page being unreadable even after 4-5 hours.